# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while releasing object of UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c

When I am trying to release the object of `UIPopoverController`,app gets crashed with message `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. See below code snippet:

```
UITableViewCell *tblcell=(UITableViewCell*)[heatsv viewWithTag:500+sender.tag];
ResourceDetail *objRDPopup=[[ResourceDetail alloc] init];
UIPopoverController *aPopover1 = [[UIPopoverController alloc]  initWithContentViewController:objRDPopup]; 
[aPopover1 setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 195)]; 
[aPopover1 presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:tblcell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[objRDPopup release];
[aPopover1 release]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popovers are not retained when you present them, so it's not safe to release them when they're still onscreen.

Assign your popover to a retained property in your viewController class instead, then release it in your viewDidUnload/dealloc as normal.